# SQL query - my D&D idea - use an array to reference multiple Ids

Tags: postgresql

I am currently learning to code and have started on SQL. I am working through my course and going to have my end project as a D&D create your own character app.

I had an idea to involve SQL to use as the db for all the creator info. Such as classes, races ect.

I have this idea to have a SQL table for the actual character info that will be populated using the Web app and filled using info from other tables. Such as a table for the character proficiencies. I am wondering is there a way that I can have an array of proficiency ID's in the character table.

EG.

```
Table characters {
  id int [pk]
  first_name
  last_name
  proficiencies <- WOULD BE ARRAY SAY [2, 3, 5]
}

Table proficiencies {
  id
  name
}
```

Comment: If you are just learning SQL, please learn proper normalization before you apply any de-normalization approaches. This is a standard many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

No you should not use an array to store a "one to many" relationship. Instead, create a new table that has a character_id column and a proficiency_id column. Then every row will be a proficiency that a character has.

Then you can get the proficiencies that a character has by joining the three tables together

[Learn more about sql relationships here](https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-sql-types-of-relations/)

PS you should name you id's like character_id and proficiency_id for clarity!

Comment: OK awesome, so have an extra table that acts as the array?

Comment: I wouldn't say the table acts as an array, As arrays typically don't map one thing to another. As an example, your table may look something like

Character_id  | proficiency_id =>  (1,1), ( 1,2), (1,3), ( 2,2) (Tuples are rows)